# how to modify behaviour of MVCGrid buttons in CRUD in ATK4

Tags: atk4, mvcgrid

In my site, i have a page which is intended to handle a basic ticket system for bug tracking and feature requests.  I need a grid to be displayed of the currently open requests with a button which allows the user to add new ones.  I also want each row to have a button called 'detail' which will either open a new page or popup a frame (dont mind which) containing the history e.g. the dates, times and any commments that the bug/issue has had, status updates or comments and a simple form to allow the user to add new responses.

So far, I create a page to which i added a CRUD and used addColumn('button','detail') to add a button to each row.

[image]

and the ATK4 code to create this is elegantly short like this

```
 <?php
  class page_ticket extends Page {
     function init() {
     parent::init();
     $p=$this;

     $team=$this->api->getTeamID();

     if (isset($_GET['detail'])) {
       $ticket=$_GET['detail'];
       $p->add('HtmlElement',null, 'crud')->setElement('h2')->set('Ticket History - ['.$ticket.']');
     } else {

       $tk=$p->add('CRUD_Ticket', null, 'crud');
       $m=$tk->setModel('Ticket', array('name', 'submit_date', 'status','ticket_type_id', 'urgency_id','description');

       $m->addCondition('status','TKO');

       $open=$this->api->db->dsql()->table('vscrum_ticket')
                  ->field('count(*)')
                  ->where('team_id',$team)
                  ->where('status','TKO')
                  ->do_getOne();
       ..   ..   ..

       $tk->grid->addQuickSearch(array('name'));
       $tk->grid->addPaginator(12);
  }

  $this->template->set('open_tickets', $open);
 } //End else detail
}

function defaultTemplate(){
    return array('page/ticket');
}
```

}

But the problem is i cant work out where the default functionality of the button is handled.  At the moment, it will by default open the same page (ticket.php) passing the parameter but what happens is it opens a new window and gives an Ajax error as shown.

[image]

I have included an if then else in the page and in the error window, it displays my output correctly which is the Ticket ID of the row where the detail button was pressed.  I can add the other detail later but why is it opening this in a new window instead of loading it in the frame ?

I assume it's the default functionality of the CRUD as the buttons are normally edit or delete but how can i override this ?

If i wanted to open a different page, rather than the same one, i assume this would also be related to overriding the default functionality of the MVCGrid buttons which opens a frame using the javascript frameURL function.

The CRUD looks like this

```
  <?php
class CRUD_Ticket extends View {
    public $form=null;
    public $grid=null;

    public $grid_class='MVCGrid';
    public $form_class='MVCForm';

    public $frame_options=null;
    function init(){
    parent::init();

    if(isset($_GET[$this->name])){
        $this->api->stickyGET($this->name);

        $this->form=$this->add($this->form_class);
        $_GET['cut_object']=$this->name;

        return;
    }

    $this->grid=$this->add($this->grid_class);
    $this->js('reload',$this->grid->js()->reload());
    $this->add_button = $this->grid->addButton('Add Ticket');
    $this->add_button->js('click')->univ()
        ->frameURL('Add Ticket',$this->api->getDestinationURL(null,array($this->name=>'new')),$this->frame_options);

    }

    function setModel($a,$b=null){
    if($this->form){
        $m=$this->form->setModel($a,$b);

        if(($id=$_GET[$this->name])!='new'){
        $m->loadData($id);
        }

        if($this->form->isSubmitted()){
        $this->form->update(); 
                    $this->form->js(null,$this->js()
                         ->trigger('reload'))->univ()->closeDialog()->execute();
        }
        return $m;
    }
    $m=$this->grid->setModel($a,$c);

    $this->grid->addColumn('button','detail');
    if($id=@$_GET[$this->grid->name]){
        $this->js()->univ()->frameURL('Ticket History',$this->api->getDestinationURL(
                    null,array($this->name=>$id)))->execute();
    }
    return $m;
    }
}
```

I tried changing the call to frameURL to in the CRUD to

```
   $this->js()->univ()->page('ticketdtl',array($this->name=>$id));
```

and

```
   $this->js()->univ()->location($this->api->getDestinationURL('tktdetail',array($this->name=>$id))
```

but these also dont work as it still redirects to the original page so i think it must be default functionality that needs overriding somewhere - just cant figure out where ?

Went back to the agiletoolkit.org page [here](http://agiletoolkit.org/whatsnew/may2011) and realised that the demo where button is added to the Grid (B1 & B2) also exhibit same behaviour.

Comment: Why did someone -1 without any explanation ? This is functionality that anyone might want in ATK4 and as I noted in the addendum yesterday, the atk4 demo page also gets an error so may be a bug in ATK4

Comment: According to FAQ - best stackoverflow questions include some source code and are for a specific programming problem.  The above is not an open ended question of discussion so why the -1 on the question ?

Comment: I'm giving +1, i see no reason for down-vote. Maybe because you forgot question mark at the end of the title.

Comment: Thanks Romans - whoever gave a -1 one with no explanation doesnt help stackoverflow as it gives no feedback to the user on why.  I will bear in mind the question mark in future as the title could be misinterpreted as a statement although it is intended as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons in Agile Toolkit Grid send a request asking for some JavaScript response. When that response arrives, it can open a frame. As a result you need to do two requests instead of one.

I have included a working example here:

http://agiletoolkit.org/codepad/gui/grid#GridButton

Comment: i had started to extend MVCGrid with a new class containing a new version of the format_button function but was sure there would be a simpler way.  Will give this a try. Thanks

Comment: That works although i added one extra thing.  My initial page contains a CRUD.  The dialog contains several elements including another CRUD and several views.  When i did as per your example, i got both the original CRUD and the content of the $_GET['keyword'] block in the dialog box.  By adding an if (!isset($_GET['keyword'] around the initial page contents, this works as expected.

Comment: that example is not ideal, it's always better to send user to a separate page, which wouldn't need any keywords to check.

Comment: I got it working with the example (two gets in page and using FrameURL but it does get messy because i want to have a form within the frame and therefore have another get for isSubmitted. I tried an alternative with a $_GET in the first page to trap the button click and to call getDestinationURL with the second page as a parameter but i get AJAXec errors again - so can you post an example of a custom button in a GRID which redirects to a different page and passes the parameter of the row pressed ? TIA

Comment: Grid also supports add-ons. I have added one more example to the codepad illustrating how to make a pop-up support through one-liner. Please give it a try.

Comment: I have it working using the custom button to open the new page BUT i havent worked out how to pass the id.  I can see it's in the attr('rel') but i wasnt able to get this using a jquery selector so must have the syntax wrong.

Comment: I also tried to just use add('button', 'detail') on the CRUD grid and put a if ($_GET['detail']) ...location(...getDestinationURL('newpage',array('id'=>$_GET['detail']) but this again gets the ajax errors  - Seems like this should be straightforward but i've spent three days so far and still don't see the logic.  The AjaxEC errors are usually appearing when there is a get missing in the page, but i have the GET - it's just not doing anything with it!

Comment: OK - got it working - just needed to add the ->execute() on the end of the getDestinationURL() and it worked fine to redirect to new page with a single $_GET looking for the label on the button - Didnt need the custom button but good to know about it as might help someone else if they want to add custom functions other than buttons - thanks